# jQuery undefined error on Windows 7 iis 7 pc

Tags: jquery

This HTML page which worked before now turns up a jquery error. Since the last time it worked, I created a new user account and attempted to setup a pc to pc ad hoc wireless network.  It's strange that these would have an effect.

Tags for libraries.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
```

The errors are

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; Tablet PC 2.0)
Timestamp: Wed, 10 Aug 2011 16:03:33 UTC


Message: 'jQuery' is undefined
Line: 10
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.core.js


Message: 'jQuery' is undefined
Line: 10
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js


Message: 'jQuery' is undefined
Line: 13
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js


Message: 'jQuery' is undefined
Line: 15
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js


Message: 'jQuery' is undefined
Line: 15
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js
```

Comment: Check if you're missing jquery, try to get it from the outside otherwise as you did with jqueryui.

Comment: Can you post the `<head>` and any `<script>` tags you have on the page throwing the error? You should use the CDN, preferably from google. E.G. `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: @atzu the libraries are from jquery.com, I edited the original message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct behavior. Just check the path in your file to jquery source - it is set to jqueryUI website.

```
http://jqueryui.com/jquery-1.5.1.js
```

Better idea (as stslavik suggested) is using one of the CDN repositories. For details check the jquery documentaion page:

```
http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery
```